# JSON filter and distinct values for array Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, json, filter, google-apps-script, pivot

I have a results set I am pulling from a query to a sql database that has 3 columns - Category, Filetype, and Status.  I am returning the set to html as a JSON and am looking to display the unique Category and the matching Filetypes for that Category that have a Status of "fail".

On my gs side I have:

```
    function checkStatus(form) {

    var conn = getConnection(); 
    var stmtquery = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Category, FileType, Status FROM ExtDocStatus WHERE AppID = ? AND Expected = 'Y'");
    stmtquery.setString(1, appID);
    var results = stmtquery.executeQuery();
    var resultsArray = [];
    while (results.next()) {
    resultsArray.push({'Category': results.getString(1),
                       'FileType': results.getString(2),
                       'Status': results.getString(3)});
        }



    return JSON.stringify(resultsArray)

  //} catch (error) {
  //  return error.toString();
  //}

}
```

I'm not too sure how to structure this on my html page but so far have:

```
function submitForm() {
        var form = $('#Form')[0];
            checkForm(function(){
            $("#submit-button")[0].value = 'Checking Status...';

            google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(function onSuccess(data) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (data == '') {
                    $("#modal-body").html("<strong>We have no records in our system for you</strong>");

                    }
                    else {
                        $.each(data.Category, function()
                        $("#modal-body").html('<p><strong>Our system indicates you have opted in for the following categories:<strong></p><ul>');
                            for(var x in data) {
                                $("#modal-body").append('<p><strong>'+data[x].Category+'</strong></p>');
                                $("#modal-body").append('<ul>')
                                $("#modal-body").append('<li><span style="color: red;"><strong>'+data[x].FileType+'</strong></span></li>');
                                $("#modal-body").append('</ul>');
                    }
                $("#submit-button")[0].value = 'Check Status';
                $("#dialog").modal('show');

            })
            .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
                alert(error);
            })
            .checkStatus(form);

            });





    }
```

As it is I would get a list of all categories and a list of all FileTypes, but want to limit just to distinct for category (regardless of filetype or status) and then list of matching filetypes that have failed statuses.  A buddy suggested creating a pivot table with (.each) and pushing data to a new array based on keys but not too sure how to implement that.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you modify the SQL query to do what you want?